# NVD3 - How to add arrow heads to the links using angular-nvd3

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I'm working from the example of the force directed graph.

krispo/angular-nvd3/blob/gh-pages/js/forceDirectedGraph.js

How would I modify this code, so that I can add arrow heads to each of the links to indicate direction?

```
$scope.options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'forceDirectedGraph',
        height: 450,
        width: (function(){ return nv.utils.windowSize().width })(),
        margin:{top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
        color: function(d){
            return color(d.group)
        },
        nodeExtras: function(node) {
            node && node
              .append("text")
              .attr("dx", 8)
              .attr("dy", ".35em")
              .text(function(d) { return d.name })
              .style('font-size', '10px');
        }
    }
};
```

So that the output looks something more like this:

http://bl.ocks.org/tomgp/d59de83f771ca2b6f1d4

which append markers as the arrowhead to the FDG.

```
defs.append("marker")
            .attr({
                "id":"arrow",
                "viewBox":"0 -5 10 10",
                "refX":5,
                "refY":0,
                "markerWidth":4,
                "markerHeight":4,
                "orient":"auto"
            })
            .append("path")
                .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5")
                .attr("class","arrowHead");
```

Here is my plunker example

http://plnkr.co/edit/rEOMRRnHx1UUj4Lu5Jui?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a issue with Angular-nvd3. Hopefully it will be resolved.
https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/issues/677